# Highchart export Button menuItems got error in IE

Tags: highcharts

I created export contextButton with menuItems like this. 
                        'exporting':{
                           'buttons': {
                                'contextButton': {

```
                                 'menuItems': [ {
                                     'text': 'Export to PNG',
                                     'onclick': function() {
                                         this.exportChart();
                                     },
                                     'separator': false
                                 },null,null,null,null

                                 ]
                            }
                        }
                }
```

When click the menuItem, chrome & firefox works fine but IE got following error in highcharts.js and cannot open the menu:

Invalid argument. highchart.js, line8 character56.
(function(){function N(a,b){var c;a||(a={});for(c in b)a[c]=b[c];

Any idea about this issue?

Also in chrome&firefox, "print" works fine. However any download like download png, download pdf not working. And I got below error in exporting.js when I click:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined.

Any idea about this?

Comment: Which IE? Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/h8ekT/1/show/ does this create the same error for you? For me this works fine. Maybe you have old version of Highcharts/Exporting module?

Comment: Thanks Pawel! The reason is because of highchart.js version issue. Thanks a lot for your help!